# Spring QueryDsl pagination filter by ACL permissions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume the following Spring JPA based repository with QueryDsl support.

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Team> {

}
```

The application uses *Access Control Lists (ACL)* in service layer for checking permission for individual resources using `@PreAuthorize(hasPermission(#id, 'Team', 'READ')` for example.

I want to allow a user to request all teams for which he has read permission. I tried to use
`@PostFilter(hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')`, that works pretty good as long as I use `Iterable<Team> findAll(Predicate predicate)`. But when I try to make use of pagination, `@PostFilter` seems to throw an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter target must be a collection, array, or stream type, but was Page 1 of 0 containing UNKNOWN instances
```

The official [Spring Security Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#data) recommends to write a custom query using `@Query` which supports pagination.

How could I write such a complex query which supports **QueryDsl's Predicate**, **Pagination** and **filtering based on permissions**?

**Approach 03/24/20**

In another [forum](https://coderanch.com/t/628088/frameworks/Spring-Data-good-filter-database) I came across the following QueryDsl based approach: Instead of a native or custom query, the [ACL tables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/appendix-schema.html) are mapped as `@Immutable` JPA entities, thus generating Q classes and using them to filter for permissions manually.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "acl_object_identity")
public class AclObjectIdentity implements Serializable {

    ...
}
```

How could you do this using a custom repository, extending `QueryDslRepositorySupport`, so that the part of the query that checks permissions is automatically appended and hidden inside of a custom repository implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Based on this [approach](https://coderanch.com/t/628088/frameworks/Spring-Data-good-filter-database) I have developed a possibility which is more a dirty workaround than a solution.

The approach is to add an additional permission filter to existing predicates, for example those generated by [web support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe). For this, the ACL tables must first be mapped as `@Immutable` JPA entities so that QueryDsl can generate the corresponding Q classes.

Such predicates to which an ACL Permission Filter should be appended are marked with the following annotation.

```
public Page<PostDTO> findAll(@QueryDslAclPermission(root = Post.class, permission = "READ") Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

    ...
}
```

This annotation holds primarily meta information about the domain type that are required for building the filter query.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface QueryDslAclPermission {

    Class<?> root();

    String permission();

    String identifier() default "id";
}
```

The actual filter query is generated and appended using the the following class and Spring's [AOP Module](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop).

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class QueryDslAclPermissionAspect {

    private PermissionFactory permissionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public QueryDslAclPermissionAspect(PermissionFactory permissionFactory) {
        this.permissionFactory = permissionFactory;
    }

    @Around(value = "execution(* *(.., @QueryDslAclPermission (*), ..))")
    public Object addPermissionFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
        Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();

        for(int index = 0; index < parameters.length; ++index) {

            if(parameters[index].getType().equals(Predicate.class) &&
                    parameters[index].isAnnotationPresent(QueryDslAclPermission.class)) {

                Predicate predicate = (Predicate) arguments[index];
                QueryDslAclPermission aclPermission = parameters[index].getAnnotation(QueryDslAclPermission.class);

                arguments[index] = addPermissionFilter(predicate, aclPermission);
            }
        }

        return joinPoint.proceed(arguments);
    }

    private Predicate addPermissionFilter(Predicate predicate, QueryDslAclPermission aclPermission) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(null == authentication || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Permission filtering not possible for unauthenticated principal");
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        PrincipalSid principalSid = new PrincipalSid(userDetails.getUsername());

        NumberPath<Long> idPath = new PathBuilderFactory().create(aclPermission.root())
                .getNumber(aclPermission.identifier(), Long.class);

        return idPath.in(selectPermitted(aclPermission.root(), principalSid,
                permissionFactory.buildFromName(aclPermission.permission()))).and(predicate);
    }

    private JPQLQuery<Long> selectPermitted(Class<?> targetType, PrincipalSid sid, Permission permission) {

        return selectAclEntry(targetType, sid, permission)
                .select(QAclEntry.aclEntry.aclObjectIdentity.objectIdIdentity);
    }

    private JPQLQuery<AclEntry> selectAclEntry(Class<?> targetType, PrincipalSid sid, Permission permission) {

        return new JPAQuery<AclEntry>().from(QAclEntry.aclEntry)
                .where(QAclEntry.aclEntry.aclObjectIdentity.id.in(selectAclObjectIdentity(targetType)
                        .select(QAclObjectIdentity.aclObjectIdentity.id))
                        .and(QAclEntry.aclEntry.aclSid.id.eq(selectAclSid(sid).select(QAclSid.aclSid.id)))
                        .and(QAclEntry.aclEntry.mask.eq(permission.getMask())));
    }

    private JPQLQuery<AclObjectIdentity> selectAclObjectIdentity(Class<?> targetType) {

        return new JPAQuery<AclObjectIdentity>().from(QAclObjectIdentity.aclObjectIdentity)
                .where(QAclObjectIdentity.aclObjectIdentity.objectIdClass.id.eq(selectAclClass(targetType)
                        .select(QAclClass.aclClass.id)));
    }

    private JPQLQuery<AclSid> selectAclSid(PrincipalSid sid) {

        return new JPAQuery<AclSid>().from(QAclSid.aclSid)
                .where(QAclSid.aclSid.sid.eq(sid.getPrincipal()));
    }

    private JPQLQuery<AclClass> selectAclClass(Class<?> targetType) {

        return new JPAQuery<AclClass>().from(QAclClass.aclClass)
                .where(QAclClass.aclClass.className.eq(targetType.getSimpleName()));
    }
}
```

**Edit 09/20/2022**

A more generic approach based on JPA's `Specification<T>` and a custom repository implementation can be found in my GitHub [Gist](https://gist.github.com/0x1C1B/ad7c0fd718945d5c38a09e5398d6da19). It is decoupled from QueryDsl.